# How to set column in report using with setDetailColumns(detailColumns) in apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, dashboard

I want to insert a  detail column in report in salesforce. I have get the data from report but unable to set the column in salesforce. Anyone have solution for that scenario?

The code and error:

```
  public PageReference SetData (){
    List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report WHERE ID = '00O90000002umtc'];
    for(Report rpt:reportList){
        reportId = (String)rpt.Id;
        Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
         // Get the report metadata
        Reports.ReportMetadata rm = describe.getReportMetadata();
        List<String> lstString = rm.getDetailColumns();
        system.debug(lstString);
        List<String> lstString1 = new List<String>();
        //For(string st : lstString){
            string st = 'Hello_dev__Price__c';
            system.debug('============================================='+st);
            If(st != null){
                lstString1.add(st);
                system.debug('=========================================='+lstString1);
               rm.setDetailColumns(lstString1);
               Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, rm, true);

            //}

          }

        }
    return null;
}
```

> reports.InvalidFilterException: [The column
>   hello_dev__merchandise__c.hello_dev__price__c is not a valid column.]
>   Error is in expression '{!SetData}' in component 
>   in page hello_dev:metadatalist: Class.reports.ReportManager.runReport:
>   line 24, column 1 Class.Hello_dev.MetaDatalist.SetData: line 122,
>   column 1 An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has
>   been notified. (reports)

Comment: Given that the method is available, [setDetailColumns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#apex_reports_ReportMetadata_setDetailColumns), what exactly is your problem?

Comment: need a set column in exist report I am using following code and it is throwing exception.

Comment: string st = 'hello_dev__merchandise__c.hello_dev__price__c';
                If(st != null){
                    lstString1.add(st);
                   rm.setDetailColumns(lstString1);
                   Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, rm, true);
                
              }

Comment: reports.InvalidFilterException: [The column hello_dev__merchandise__c.hello_dev__price__c is not a valid column.]
Error is in expression '{!SetData}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page hello_dev:metadatalist: Class.reports.ReportManager.runReport: line 24, column 1
Class.Hello_dev.MetaDatalist.SetData: line 122, column 1

An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (reports)

Comment: I've edited that information into the question. (I'm assuming you don't presently have editing rights.)

Comment: First thin to try is just `string st = 'hello_dev__price__c';` if you haven't already; think the value should be the API name of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class SetMetaData {
    public String selectedObject {set; get;}
    public String Selectfields {set; get;}
    Map mapObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    string sID {get;set;}

```
public SetMetaData (){
    sID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    System.debug(sID); 
}

public List<SelectOption> getObjects(){
    List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = mapObjects.Values();
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    for(Schema.SObjectType f: gd){

        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getName(),f.getDescribe().getName()));
    }
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getFields(){
    //selectedObject = 'Account';
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    if(mapObjects.containskey(selectedObject)){
        system.debug('===================='+selectedObject);
        Schema.SObjectType s12 = mapObjects.get(selectedObject);
        List<Schema.SObjectType> objects = new List<Schema.SObjectType>{s12};

        for(Schema.SObjectType objType: objects){
            for(Schema.SObjectField fld: objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
                options.add(new SelectOption(fld.getDescribe().getName(),fld.getDescribe().getName()));
                System.debug('API Field Name =  '+fld.getDescribe().getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return options;
 }

public PageReference SetData (){
    //Get the Report data in json format
    string  st = selectedObject+'.'+Selectfields;
    Http hr = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/'+sID);
    req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req1.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res1 = hr.send(req1);
    String body =  res1.getBody();
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+res1);
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+body);

    //map Json for Common data request
    Map<String, Object> root = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
    Map<String, Object> AllResultoObj = (Map<String, Object>)root.get('reportMetadata'); 
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+AllResultoObj);

    List<Object> rowList =  (List<Object>)AllResultoObj.get('detailColumns');
    System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+rowList);

    //Create the body for send the data in report
    list<object> lststr = rowList;
    System.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'+lststr);
    List<Object> str = new List<Object>();
    string myListStirng;
    for(object objstr : lststr){
        str.add('"'+objstr+'"');
        myListStirng = string.join(str,',');
       system.debug('********************'+myListStirng);
    }
    for(object ob : rowList){
        System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+ob);
        if(ob == st){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'This Column already exist in report'));
        }
        else {
            string BodyParse = '{"reportMetadata" : {"detailColumns" : ['+myListStirng+',"'+st+'"]}}';
            System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+BodyParse);
            //Post the data and save the reports
            system.debug('============'+st);
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/'+sID+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
            req.setBody(BodyParse);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            string bodyres = res.getBody();
            if(bodyres.contains('errorCode'))
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, bodyres));
            else    
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'This Column has been inserted in report'));
            system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+res);
            system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+bodyres);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

Public PageReference delData(){
     //Get the Report data in json format
    string  st = selectedObject+'.'+Selectfields;
    Http hr = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/'+sID);
    req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req1.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res1 = hr.send(req1);
    String body =  res1.getBody();
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+res1);
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+body);

    //map Json for Common data request
    Map<String, Object> root = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
    Map<String, Object> AllResultoObj = (Map<String, Object>)root.get('reportMetadata'); 
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+AllResultoObj);

    List<Object> rowList =  (List<Object>)AllResultoObj.get('detailColumns');
    System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+rowList);

    //Create the body for send the data in report
    list<object> lststr = rowList;
    List<Object> delStr = new List<Object>();
    string delString;
    for(object ob : lststr){
        System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+ob);
        if(ob != st){
            delStr.add('"'+ob+'"');
            delString = string.join(delStr,',');
        }
        else {
            string BodyParse = '{"reportMetadata" : {"detailColumns" : ['+delString+']}}';
            System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+BodyParse);
            //Post the data and save the reports
            system.debug('============'+st);
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/'+sID+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
            req.setBody(BodyParse);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'This Column has been deleted in report'));
            system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++'+res);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Pass the report id in Url as a para meter

Comment: Any one need  vf page we can post here